# The type or namespace name 'Capture' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.Graphics' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to C# althought have experience with other programming languages.

I am trying to get this demo code to build:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/SimpleRecorder

I've installed Visual Studio 2019 free edition plus I installed everything else I thought might possibly be needed such as the.NET framework.

One of the errors is as follows:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Capture' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.Graphics' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    CaptureEncoder  C:\Users\andrewstuart\devel\screenrecorder\CaptureEncoder\CaptureFrameWait.cs   9   Active
```

But many other errors appear in the Visual Studio log when I try to build the project.  Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong and how to get this project to build?

thanks

Comment: That sample is for a [UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide) - and those use WinRT libaries - have you installed the [c#/WinRT package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT/)?